# How to find and remove/replace data in .resx in bulk?

Tags: regex, replace, resx

I have a solution with lots of .resx files. They have a particular element in many of them and I want to remove that element in each resx or replace it in bulk.

The solution is in TFS 2010 so the preference is to use Visual Studio to do the job and that way it will also checkout the files and I can create shelvesets/do checkins without having to manually check the files I need out.

The versions of VS I have available to do this are VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 (I've heard their find/replace capabilities may be different in each version).

E.g. foo.resx content has this:

```xml
<data name="SomeName">
  <value>SomeValue</Value>
</data>
<data name="SomeOther1">
  <value>SomeValue</Value>
</data>
<data name="SomeOther2">
  <value>SomeValue</Value>
</data>
```

And I want to get rid of all instances of the data with name "SomeName" and leave:

```xml
<data name="SomeOther1">
  <value>SomeValue</Value>
</data>
<data name="SomeOther2">
  <value>SomeValue</Value>
</data>
```

Is this possible? With regex? Otherwise?

Comment: You should use XSLT for this.

Comment: More importantly, what version of TFS are you using, in case of 2012 or 2013, you can use a Local Workspace, which will solve the checkout issue. And then any XML processing tool will do the trick, a short Powershell snippet?

Comment: I wouldn't use Visual Studio's Find Replace for anything other than simple text replacement. Copy the XML to Notepad++ or Sublime Text and do it there.

Comment: Sorry jessehouwing. Unfortunately we are still on TFS 2010.

Comment: @garryh there are hundreds of these files. I'm trying to work out a way to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, you can use (ctrl+h, regular expression search mode):

`<data name="SomeName">\r\n.*\r\n<\/data>\r\n`

And since VS's so called "regex" is a nightmare, I won't ever answer that kind of question again. But here you go, for VS 2010:

`:b*\<data name="SomeName"\>\n:b*.*\n:b*.*data\>`

This ain't pretty.

Comment: Yes the help pages are pretty low level and missing high level examples. Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 0):

The full solution I used was the following:

1) Checkout resx files using TF.exe cmdline (where local path is the root of where you want to search from)

```
tf checkout /recursive *.resx
```

2) Then remove the property with a find/replace in Notepad++ with this regex string:

```
\r\n..<data name=\"SomeValue\"*\>.*?</data>
```

3) Then undo resx which were not changed with TFS Power Toys:

```
tfpt uu . /noget /recursive
```

Done.